# Merge two similar rows in SQL

Tags: sql, db2

I want to merge empty space in column TPMDE8  `where TPTTYP = 'AU'` with TPMDE8 `where TPTTYP='U'`, now it looks like

| TPTTYP | JL | FROM | CEL | BUFOR | ART | PODJETE | TPMDE8 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| U | 222037038 | HRL PS 0-0-0 | PNG K1 1-2-3 | PNG01IN01 | 27923 |  | 2212141308 |
| AU | 222037038 | HRL PS 0-0-0 | PNG K1 1-2-3 | PNG01IN01 | 27923 | 14-12-2022 13:09:42 |  |

Is it possible to do this using SQL and in final query i can see both values when `where TPTTYP='AU'`?

I want it looks like this:

| TPTTYP | JL | FROM | CEL | BUFOR | ART | PODJETE | TPMDE8 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AU | 222037038 | HRL PS 0-0-0 | PNG K1 1-2-3 | PNG01IN01 | 27923 | 14-12-2022 13:09:42 | 2212141308 |

Full query

```
select tpttyp, TPLENR as JL, (tpvber|| ' ' || tpvreg|| '-' ||tpvhor|| '-' ||tpvver) as Z,
(tpnber|| ' ' || tpnreg|| '-' ||tpnhor|| '-' ||tpnver) as na,
TPPPLZ as bufor,
trim(tpiden) as art, 
(to_date(right('00' || TPTSTA,2) || '-' || right('00' || TPTSMO,2) || '-' || TPTSJH || right('00' || TPTSJA,2) || right('00' || tptsst,2) || ':' || right('00' ||tptsmi ,2) || ':' || right('00'|| tptsse ,2),'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')) as Podjete,
tpmde8

from xyz
where
...
```

Comment: Please don't link to images of data. Post data as formatted text in question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the rows are related by `JL` column values.

```
WITH XYZ (TPTTYP, JL, PODJETE, TPMDE8) AS 
(
  VALUES 
    ('U',   222037038, NULL, 2212141308)
  , ('AU',  222037038, '14-12-2022 13:09:42', NULL)
)
SELECT AU.TPTTYP, AU.JL, AU.PODJETE, U.TPMDE8
FROM XYZ AU
JOIN XYZ U ON U.JL = AU.JL
WHERE AU.TPTTYP = 'AU' AND U.TPTTYP = 'U'
```

| TPTTYP | JL | PODJETE | TPMDE8 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AU | 222037038 | 14-12-2022 13:09:42 | 2212141308 |